# How the glibc strlen() implementation works

Tags: c, string, performance, glibc

The `strlen()` from K&R takes only a few lines.

```
int strlen(char *s)
{
    char *p = s;
    while (*p != '\0')
        p++;
    return p - s;
}
```

But the [glibc version](http://www.stdlib.net/~colmmacc/strlen.c.html) is much longer. For simplicity, I removed all the comments and the 64-bit implementation, the extracted version `strlen()` looks like this:

```
size_t strlen(const char *str)
{
    const char *char_ptr;
    const unsigned long int *longword_ptr;
    unsigned long int longword, magic_bits, himagic, lomagic;

    for (char_ptr = str; ((unsigned long int) char_ptr 
             & (sizeof (longword) - 1)) != 0; ++char_ptr)
       if (*char_ptr == '\0')
           return char_ptr - str;

    longword_ptr = (unsigned long int *) char_ptr;

    himagic = 0x80808080L;
    lomagic = 0x01010101L;

    for (;;)
    { 
        longword = *longword_ptr++;

        if (((longword - lomagic) & himagic) != 0)
        {
            const char *cp = (const char *) (longword_ptr - 1);

            if (cp[0] == 0)
                return cp - str;
            if (cp[1] == 0)
                return cp - str + 1;
            if (cp[2] == 0)
                return cp - str + 2;
            if (cp[3] == 0)
                return cp - str + 3;
        }
    }
}
```

With the help of the very helpful comment (click [here](http://www.stdlib.net/~colmmacc/strlen.c.html)), I got most of how this works. Instead of checking for `'\0'` byte by byte, the glibc `strlen()` checks every word(4 bytes in 32-bit machine, 8 byte in 64-bit machine). In this way, when the string is relatively long, the performance can be improved.

It checks the first few characters by reading byte by byte, until `char_ptr` is aligned on a `longword` boundary. Then it uses a loop to check if the `longword` has any bytes with of all-zeros. If there is, check which byte, and return the result.

The part I don't get is, how does this check if one byte in `longword` is all-zeros?

```
if (((longword - lomagic) & himagic) != 0)
```

I can build a `longword` value of `0x81818181`, which can make `0x81818181 - 0x01010101) & 0x80808080` not equal to `0`, but there are no all-zero bytes.

Is this related with the fact that ASCII values range from `0` to `127`, so `0x81` isn't valid ASCII? But I don't think the C standard forces strings to use ASCII.

Comment: Related [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/57650895) has an answer that addresses the type-punning UB, and links to glibc's hand-written asm that's actually used on most platforms.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20090309052952/http://www.stdlib.net/~colmmacc/strlen.c.html for the helpful comment mentioned above.

Comment: Your link seems to be broken. Here's another one I could find https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/strlen.c

Answer (score 24):

I figured it out. Can't believe it's that simple, I spent the last half an hour on it.

It's OK that the check

```
if (((longword - lomagic) & himagic) != 0)
```

lets values like `0x81818181` pass, because if it passes, the following test on every byte would not return since there are no all-zero byte. So the loop can continue to test the next `longword`.

---

The algorithm behind the check is based on [Determine if a word has a zero byte](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord)

```
unsigned int v; 
bool hasZeroByte = ~((((v & 0x7F7F7F7F) + 0x7F7F7F7F) | v) | 0x7F7F7F7F);
```

In 2's complement, `- 0x01010101` has the same effect with `+ 0xFEFEFEFF`. The difference is because glibc doesn't have `v & 0x7F7F7F7F`, which makes sure the bytes in the word has the most significant bit of `0`. This prevents examples like `0x81818181`, but glibc omits it because it doesn't have to let it pass as stated earlier, The check is correct as long as it won't miss any word that does have all-zero bytes.

Comment: They could have used `(((v) - 0x01010101UL) & ~(v) & 0x80808080UL)` which doesn't give false positives but requires two additional operations. I guess a compromise was made since without ANDing with `~(v)` it works well for ASCII strings, and a great deal of information processed is ASCII.

Comment: @HristoIliev Yeah, I guess they chose not to do that because most of real life strings in fact contains only ASCII values.

Comment: Subtracting 0x01010101 is the equivalent of adding 0xFEFEFEFF. The 0xFE allows for the carry that will happen for any byte that isn't 0x00.

Comment: @godel9 You are right, They are different, I've fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad that the user who asked the original question figured it out, but it sure would be nice to get a higher level explanation for those who aren't familiar with "bit twiddling" and would still like to understand what is going on.