# strncpy implementation too complicated in glibc

Tags: c, glibc, strncpy

I'm trying to understand **string.h** functions. Here is my own implementation of strncpy()

```
char * my_strncpy(char *dst, const char* src, int n)
{
    char *orig = dst;
    const char *hold = src;
    int count = 0, remain = 0;
    while(*(hold++))
            count++;
    if ( n > count )
    {
            remain = n - count;
            n = count;
    }
    while(n--)
            *dst++ = *src++;
    while(remain--)
            *dst++ = '\0';
    return orig;
}
```

But while looking at glibc implementation [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strncpy.c;h=0915e036d61b98581eee928d7bb1e532e759d12d;hb=HEAD), I'm wondering why it is too big and complicated.

I tested for execution time using "**time**" command. Both functions run almost same. 
Can someone share knowledge on glibc **strncpy()** and what I'm missing in my_strncpy().

Comment: It is a little more complicated because, AFAICT, it does not count the chars before it copies, and it seems to have some kind of simple loop unrolling going on. Not sure if that is really much faster, though. You'd have to time/profile both to find out.

Comment: Aparently it copies 4 `char`s on every for loop iteration. After finishing copying these 4-char chuncks, the code at `last_char` is used to copy the remanining (<4) characters. Ultimately the destination buffer is filled with `\0`s. The logic does not seem very complicated to me, however I'm not sure of the potential performance benefits.

Comment: The glibc version will have a distinct speed advantage the longer the string and the larger the number of characters to be copied. Generally the additional code gymnastics are to prevent branching at the assembly level which is what provides the speed advantage. For another good example, look at the implementation of `strlen`

Comment: I suppose that you have forgotten something in the while(remain--) loop.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I assume you are right. It should not be faster for short strings, but it might outperform the rather simple implementation posted here for long strings.

Comment: I'm not an expert on their reasoning by any stretch, but reading a number of their implementations, there is usually sound reasoning why they do what they do (aligning on boundaries, etc..). Other times, the glibc functions are just hold-overs from days-gone-by as well.

Comment: I calculated time for both, result was same. I didn't try for longer string of-course. Thanks all, i got some proper reason.

Comment: @Manül: in while(remain--) loop i am just filling zeros in the remaining spaces after copy, as the standard strncpy() implementation says.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: You are right. I calculated execution time for bigger string. Here is the difference.

glibc implementation:
real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.000s

My Implementation
real    0m0.119s
user    0m0.116s
sys     0m0.000s

Comment: @SivaPadhy, are you sure? you don't fill the remaining spaces, you are always NULL-terminating in the same position in your `while(remain--)`

Comment: @AlterMann: Thanks for the observation.I just missed to increment the pointer. Modified.

Comment: Generally when timing functions against glibc implementations, try at least 1000000 iterations and test against short strings (<16 chars) and longer strings (>32 chars), etc.. Your implementations for short strings may even be faster, but I've not been able to beat glibs implementations for long strings.

Comment: Related: [How the glibc strlen() implementation works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021066/how-the-glibc-strlen-implementation-works),

Comment: Your function invokes undefined behavior if passed the address of a non-zero-terminated array of characters, which is allowed by the standard, and definitely corresponds to actual practice. This also mean it is possible to make your version very slow with long source strings.

Answer (score 1):

From a modern C programming perspective, that "Glibc" code is very badly written. It looks like a collection of premature optimizations for one particular platform with 32 bit alignment. If the compiler is crap, then you'll have to group bytes in units of the preferred alignment and copy them one such unit at a time. That's the main reason why the code looks so weird.

I would guess that the code was likely written a long time ago, when compilers were a lot worse at optimizing code and CPUs had less hardware support for things like these. The inconsistent, seemingly random way that they switch back and forth between prefix to postfix increment also suggests that the code was written for a poor compiler.

Apart from pre-mature optimization, the code is complete spaghetti, which there is no sensible explanation for. The complete lack of comments also suggests that the code was written by a bad programmer.

So to sum it up, there may or may not be various historical reasons why they wrote the code in this way, but there are lots of bad programming practice in the code which can't be dismissed as pre-mature optimizations.

Just dismiss that code as rubbish.

---

Also please note that the `strncpy` function is mainly obsolete and should be avoided. `strncpy` was only meant to be used for an ancient string format in Unix. [It was never intended to be a safe version of `strcpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-is-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-to-be-insecure). On the contrary, the function is dangerous and known to cause a lots of bugs because of accidental missing null terminations.

The standard specification of `strncpy` also forces it to do a lot of pointless things, like checking for null termination when you already know the length in advance. Also, one may wonder what good it does anyone to fill the remaining characters after the first `\0` with even more `\0`. All of these pointless requirements make the function needlessly slow.

So there is never a reason to use `strncpy` anywhere in modern C code. The proper way to copy strings of a known length is this:

```
memcpy(str1, str2, str2len + 1);
```

Comment: `strncpy()` is still good for explicitly null-padding a string to a certain number of bytes.

Comment: @user3477950 No it isn't. Use memcpy() followed by memset().

Comment: why isn't it? Also, I'm not sure about your note about premature optimization either. This is library code, there definitely is some excuse for writing more obscure but faster code so that *users* of the library don't have to hand-craft their version of optimized functions because the library functions are insufficiently fast. The lack of comments may be a point, but this implementation of `str(n)cpy` is quite common and anyone who has encountered the switch-trick will recognize it, so there's no much need for comments at all.

Comment: @user3477950 Because strncpy is unsafe and slow. I've already given the reasons in my answer. And no, of course there is no excuse for programmers of libraries to write obfuscated code with no comments or other documentation. Generally, it does not make sense to optimize code on the high level of libraries, if you want the code to be portable. Unless of course, this code is specific for a certain compiler port. In that case, it most likely makes more sense to write it in assemble, which in my experience is far more common practice for the standard library copy functions.

Comment: @Lundin, `memcpy` seems as dangerous as `strncpy` (should not overlap ), do you mean `memmove`?

Comment: @Lundin `strncpy()` is unsafe if you don't use it properly. Just like almost any other C function dealing with strings. As to its speed: if it's "slow", then so is `memcpy()` and `strcpy()`. That's not a reason. "Generally, it does not make sense to optimize code on the high level of libraries" - it absolutely positively does. Optimization should happen in libraries so that user code doesn't have to worry about that. The trick glibc implements works (and is often used) on most 32-bit systems (Linux, BSD, OS X and even Windows).

Comment: @AlterMann The overlap issue is there for most functions in the standard. Most often overlapping is not a problem. In the very rare case where it is, you can indeed use memmove. The main concern about `strncpy` being unsafe is [the null termination issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869883/why-is-strncpy-insecure).

Comment: @user3477950 Again, the optimization should happen in _the compiler port of the library for one specific platform_. Also 64 bit CPUs have been on the market for quite a while, making this code pre-mature optimization for historical reasons.

Comment: +1 `strncpy` is susceptible to a variety of exploits, @downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: As usual on Stack Overflow, the down vote likely originates from above the comment debate, rather than because of something in the actual answer.

Comment: Full story of `strncpy`: [How can code that tries to prevent a buffer overflow end up causing one?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/07/348437.aspx).

Comment: Wait, what? `memcpy(str1, str2, str2len + 1);` is just a long way to write `strcpy(str1, str2);`

Comment: @domen No, strcpy checks for null termination, so it is considerably slower with the extra checks and branches.