# Rewriting strlen() in C

Tags: c, string, function, loops, function-definition

if anyone has ever wanted to try and rewrite a string function in `C`, would this code work to replace the standard `strlen()` function?
I have not been able to run this code because I am sitting in my car typing it on my iPhone.

```
int strlen(char * s) {
      int i = 0, sum = 0;
      char c = s[0];

      while(c != '\0') {
            sum++;
            c = s[++i];
      }
      return sum;
}
```

You feedback is so much appreciated!

Comment: Only change the name since the real function have the same name! Also whats the question here? you started a question and not a blog!

Comment: `strlen` returns `size_t`. From the performance point of view, your function has much more to do to beat the standard function. Read [How the glibc strlen() implementation works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021066/how-the-glibc-strlen-implementation-works)

Comment: Ask code review functions on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is your car moving?  If it is, I suggest that you stop programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: On entering and exiting the `while` loop, both `i` and `sum` always have the same value. Removing `i` and `sum++;`, as well as replacing `c = s[++i];` with `c = s[++sum];` doesn't change the algorithm. Since you are typing this on a cell phone you should probably also replace `sum` with `l` to save on keystrokes. And btw, are you telling me that you cannot run a C compiler on your iPhone? Doesn't that make it somewhat shitty for a developer? Then again, Steve never was one, so why care about developers.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to rewrite standard C function `strlen` then you should follow [the declaration conventions](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.24.6.3) of the function.

> ```
> size_t strlen(const char *s);
> ```

First of all it should have return type `size_t` and the parameter shall have qualifier `const` that you could use the function with constant character arrays.
Also such a name as `sum` is not very suitable for this function. In your function you have too many local variables.

I would write the function the following way

```
size_t strlen( const char *s ) 
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] ) ++n;

    return n;
}
```

The other way is to use only pointers. For example

```
size_t strlen( const char *s ) 
{
    const char *p = s;

    while ( *p ) ++p;

    return p - s;
}
```

Comment: Unclear why someone DV this? +1 best answer.

Comment: @chux  Do not seek any reason. Simply someone do not want that my answer were upvoted.:)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it would work, but you don't need 2 integers, so it's overly complex.
`[]` lookup might be slow - pointer manipulation might be faster.

```
int myStrlen(char *s)
{
    int len = 0;
    while(*s != 0) {
        s++;
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Comment: Very true about this. Thanks!!

Comment: @John one doubt... string is terminated by '/0' then why are we comparing *s with 0?

Comment: You could use `'\0'`, if you wanted to be explicit, but 0 will work too.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for an `int` counter.

```
size_t myStrlen(char *s)
{
 char *e=s;
 while(*e!='\0')e++;
 return e-s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work. While the function can be optimized. Something like

```
 int my_strlen(char *s) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (*s++) sum++;
    return sum;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are different methods to write down code for strlen:

**Without Using Pointers:**

int mystrlen(char s[]) {

```
int i = 0;

while (s[i]!='\0')
 {
  i++;
 }
```

return i;

}

**With Pointers:**

int strlength(char const *s) {

```
int l=0;                                                    

while(*s1!='\0')                                      
{
  l++;
  s++;
}

return l;
```

}

**Without Counter:**

int my_strlen(char const *s) {

```
char *p=s;

while(*p!='\0')
     p++;

return(p-s);
```

}

**Using Recursion :**

int mystrlen(char const *s) {

```
 if(*s==0) 
      return 0;

 return mystrlen(s+1)+1;
```

}

Answer (score -2):

The actual functionality is much more than what you have written.

- Consider a scenario, where you have allocated a size of 100 to your pointer. And you forgot to add the '\0' as the last char for your array. How are you going to handle this situation? You cannot keep on incrementing the counter and keep looking for '\0'
- Arrays have a max size. Your pointer string length function should also have a realistic length. you cannot keep on iterating the counter and look for '\0'. What if you enter another processes memory location and you start reading and writing to that application memory? You would end up messing multiple applications.
- Depending on the type of compiler, it may or may not allocate memory sequentially. How are you going to handle this situation?

In short, you should work on malloc/new first. Understand it end to end and then try working on this.

Comment: Bounds-checking isn't normally done with C arrays and strings... it's up to the programmer to keep track.  Crashes from calling `strlen()` on unterminated strings aren't particularly rare even without a home-rolled function.

Comment: A _string_ in C _always_ has a terminating `'\0'`, else it is not a string.  OP said "string function", so `char * s` always points to memory with a terminating `'\0'`.  OTOH, OP could have asked for the length of a `char` array with a limit as this answer proposes.  Not a bad idea, but then the function name should not be `str..()`

Comment: if i create a char array and if i do not give the last char as '\0' then the compiler throws relevant warnings when i try to access out of the allocated memory. How is it attained without handlig?

Comment: @kris123456 If `strlen()` were doing bounds-checking, it'd give a runtime error, not a compiler error... but it can't be, since the array length isn't available to it at runtime.  Functions that do use the array length need to have it passed explicitly as an additional parameter (which isn't done for `strlen()` or most other string functions in C).